# Checking entry hasn't already being made

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically have a lead model which belongs to a listing, if a lead has already been created by the user logged in for the same listing I would like another not to be made and for an error to return instead.

My code:

```
if Listing.lead.where(email: current_user.email).any?
  redirect_to :back, alert: "You have already submitted an enquiry to this franchise"
else
*other code*
end
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? It's still making more.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your code is doing unless you have scoped 'lead.'

Run the check directly on the Lead model.

```
if Lead.where(listing_id: xx, email: current_user.email).present?
## code
```